# MySQL 8.0.21.0 - database initialization error during installation

Tags: mysql, database, initialization

whatever I do I can't finish the successful MySQL installation via community installer.

I tried changing the template ini file, and my.ini file in ProgramData before hitting "Execute" button (lowercase_table_names set to both 1 and 0), but nothing seems to work.

Here's my log:

Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...

Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.21...

Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on --lower-case-table-names=1...

'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.21) initializing of server in progress as process 4424

InnoDB initialization has started.

Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2

InnoDB Database creation was aborted with error Generic error. You may need to delete the ibdata1 file before trying to start up again.

Data Dictionary initialization failed.

The newly created data directory C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data\ by --initialize is unusable. You can remove it.

Aborting

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.21)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Process for mysqld, with ID 4424, was run successfully and exited with code 1.

Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.21.

Database initialization failed.

Ended configuration step: Initializing database (may take a long time)

Comment: mysql tries to create a file in yoir data directpry and can't so check the permissions and if there is enough space and check the venet viewer if here are more problems

Comment: @nbk Thank you for the reply, you are right, the permissions on all folders in MySQL in Program Data are set to read-only, but unfortunately the attribute cannot be removed (I tried removing attribute via attrib - r + s C:\ProgramData\MySQL, manually by giving permissions to all users and setting the inheritance, turning off the real time protection on my antivirus - nothing seems to be working.- it always keeps reverting to read only (Windows 10 frequent issue).

Comment: try the permission on C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Data  the user wshould have all rights and users has at least read rights, changen them and see that you give the rights to all following elements